# Separate code from phone number

Tags: .net, vb.net-2010

User enters phone number. My task is to separate the country code from it by matching it to all the rows of column "code" in datafile "_pricelist". The code and phone number cannot be entered separate. That is what I came up with which is not working

```
'Separating code from Phone number'
Public Sub code_seperator()
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim n As Integer = 0 
    For Each row In _pricelist.Rows
        If phone_number.ToString <> _pricelist.Rows(2).ToString Then
           phone_number = phone_number.Substring(0, phone_number.Length - n)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next
    code = phone_number
End Sub
```

Help me with it. Thank You.

Comment: What formats of phone number are permitted? for example, is +33 46758-69676 considered a valid phone number or is it digits only without whitespace?

Comment: @MattCoubrough digits without white spaces. Not even 0's before codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jonobral is correct, your line:

```
If phone_number.ToString <> _pricelist.Rows(2).ToString Then
```

is comparing phone_number to a String representation of the entire second DataRow of _pricelist every time through the loop rather than to Column 2 of each row in turn (which is what I assume you were trying to do?)

Using his code you are then getting a Length cannot be 0 as soon as the variable n is greater than the length of the phone_number String. Can you see why?

Of course, there are some other problems too...

I might need you to rephrase the question because I might not be understanding you correctly,  but assuming that:

_pricelist.Columns(2) is a column containing all valid country codes

and

phone_number is a String containing only digits which always begin with a valid international country code of 1 to 4 digits

and

that you are trying to determine which international dialling code is matched...

then

here is one simple approach (although there are more efficient methods available)

```
Public Function GetCodeFromPhNum(ByVal phone_number As String) As String
    Dim code_to_test As String

    For test_length As Integer = 4 To 1 Step -1
        code_to_test = phone_number.Substring(0,test_length)
        For Each row In _pricelist.Rows    
            If code_to_test = row(2).ToString Then 
                Return code_to_test                                  
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' if we get here, we have tried every possibility'
    ' return an empty string, (could throw an error instead)'
    Return ""

End Function

'then to use the function:'

Dim code As String = GetCodeFromPhNum(phone_number)
If code <> "" Then
    ' country code is valid ... '
Else 
    ' country code is invalid ... '
End If
```

It should be noted that there are plenty of more efficient ways to perform this matching (especially if your Data is sorted), and I haven't used VB for about 15 years so I can't be 100% sure my code is entirely valid sorry, but I hope this helps.

Please try to understand the code.

Note that the above code will fail if the passed in phone_number is fewer than 4 digits. That's because the line code_to_test = phone_number.Substring(0,test_length) will fail. You can correct this by checking if test_length <= Len(phone_number).

I should probably point out that decomposing your code into smaller units Subroutines and Functions is always a good idea.

I should also point out that referring to a data column by its name is almost always preferable to using its index, in other words:

```
row("Code_Column_Name")
```

is better than

```
row(2)
```

because it makes the code more readable, prevents against mistakes like the one you made with _pricelist.Rows(2) and is safer in the case where the Column index for the dialling code ever changes in the future.

Comment: Thank You. It was a very detailed answered. and it helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by changing the If sentence as follow:
* If phone_number.ToString <> row(2).ToString Then *
As you are evaluating the current row in the For Each statement.

And write an Else because once the code is found should exit and return the Sub:
* If phone_number.ToString <> row(2).ToString Then
      phone_number = phone_number.Substring(0, phone_number.Length - n)
      n = n + 1
  Else
      Exit For
  End If *

Answer (score 0):

And this is how the final working code looks like: 
Credits: @MattCoubrough

```
'Seperating code from Phone number'
Public Sub code_parsing()
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim temp As String = phone_number
    For l As Integer = temp.Length To 1 Step -1
        temp = temp.Remove(temp.Length - 1, 1)
        For Each row In _pricelist.Rows
            If temp.ToString = row("code").ToString Then
                code = temp
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank You mates.